# What should the tagline of Travel.StackExchange be?

Tags: discussion, beta

From: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/

> 1. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?
>
> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an
>   elevator with a friendly stranger. You
>   have precisely one floor to describe
>   your community to them. What would you
>   say? The elevator pitch is a brief
>   sentence that describes what your site
>   is about. Every word counts!
>
> Once decided, it can be sliced and
>   diced to form:
>
> ```
> **the tagline**
> the motto
> the blurb under the logo
> a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
> perhaps eventually the domain name in some form
> ```

As such, while there's a lot to think about, perhaps throwing around some tagline ideas will also give us a feel for what we want from the site?

Comment: Where do you want to go today? ([kidding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_do_you_want_to_go_today%3F) ;-)

Comment: How about: Vamos!

Comment: How about: Ticket to Ride

Comment: How about: Take a Hike

Comment: How about: Get lost!

Comment: And revisited six months later: **[The site's tag-line / slogan](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1073)**

Comment: Gah, I was trying to find this yearler!

Comment: "elevator pitch" and "tagline" are **utterly unrelated**.  An elevator pitch is what it says, a pitch.  (A pitch, just as in Hollywood or any business field, lasts for say, oh, a minute.)  A 'tagline" is a specific thing in advertising (ask someone from the ad world if you're unfamiliar with it); examples include "coke is it" or "just do it", and so on.  A tagline has utterly no connection, at all, to a "pitch". The question should be completely edited.  It's embarrassing when terms are completely mixed-up like this, especially on a site that is ultimately about words.

Answer (score 5):

"No rest for the travel obsessed"

Answer (score 4):

"Q&A for travellers, and travellers-to-be"

Answer (score 0):

The place to learn about trips and destinations, and how to be a better traveller.

Comment: It's much better if i read that with a Borat accent in my head :)

Comment: that's the only good one, well done. (the others are silly attempts at sounding like ad copy, by non ad writers)