# The site's tag-line / slogan

Tags: discussion, design

Jin is looking at launching the site soon and [wanted to know](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7702292#7702292) what tag-line we use.

The line from the [Area 51 Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591) was:

> Q&A site for road warriors and seasoned travelers.

Personally I've never liked the 'road warriors' part.

Anyway, we need a tagline for the top of the page.  Please add suggestions below, and vote for the ones you like the best.

Comment: Last time we asked ourselves this question: **[What should the tagline of Travel.StackExchange be?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/164)**

Comment: I knew it was somewhere, couldn't find it earlier

Comment: Type "tagline" in the search box in the top right (-:

Comment: I wonder whatever happened to the tagline? Will it be included in the UI design later, or did someone decide we should just forget about it?

Comment: @@Jonik it's coming still, according to Jin.  Indeed in the source code meta, there's still the old 'for road warriors..." tagline.

Answer (score 13):

> On the road with experienced travellers

Comment: I like this very much, especially because of the [Jack Kerouac reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_road).

Comment: It does have the wrong number of "l"s for some percentage of people though, as has been pointed out.

Comment: @hippietrail: You say "tomato", I say "tomahto" :-) Besides, it will never have the right number of "l"'s for everybody.

Comment: @mindcorrosive: I think you mean You say "tomayto", I say "tomato". The fact that it can never have the right number of "l"s for everybody is the only thing I don't like about it. Otherwise I love it. Maybe we could have yet another gimmick that randomly uses 1 or 2 "l"s (-:

Answer (score 7):

> Travel Q&A with people who have been there

Answer (score 6):

Another:

> Q&A With Experienced Travellers

('Seasoned' keeps reminding me of the cooking.SE site - "Seasoned Advice")

Comment: this should be +1 as I can't vote for it, but want to :)

Comment: Oh you said what I kept saying - sorry (-:

Answer (score 5):

And continuing the combinations and permutations:

> Q&A on travel and destinations: we've been there!

Comment: This sounds good! (I took the liberty to tweak "Q & A" into "Q&A" which is used across Stack Exchange.)

Comment: I'm not really a fan of the "destinations" specifically in there. So far we get the right number of destination questions, but if we push a little bit I think we could end up with too many questions about places that are not really travel questions.

Answer (score 4):

I want to avoid the word traveller because some people spell it traveler and whichever you pick, the rest of the world will think you got it wrong or they'll be offended. (Notice the mix and match throughout the rest of the answers to this question). Ditto travelling.

> Q & A on travel and destinations: anywhere, any reason, any budget

My issue with "road warrior" is that it implies business travel.

Comment: JavaScript and reverse GeoLocation to the rescue! Then only people with one or the other disabled will be offended (-;

Comment: My issue with "Road Warrior" is that it was the dumb American name for the Australian movie "Mad Max 2".

Comment: I really like the **We've been there** part! Let's come up with a few variations on just that bit!

Comment: I like your suggestions, but could you please put them in different answers so they can be voted on separately?

Comment: Done! This one shortened and two others added

Answer (score 4):

> Q&A for travellers, and travellers-to-be

(A [suggestion by fredley](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/231/583) from the similar meta question asked 1½ years ago.)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Kate Gregory's answer](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1083/140):

- We've been there!
- Travel Q&A from people who've been there.
- Travel questions answered by people who've been there.
- We can help because we've been there.

(I'm sure there's a really sweet variation of this idea that we can all love.)

Comment: "Travel Q&A WITH People who have been there" would be my vote.  I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

Got here a bit late to the party, but:

> Sharing the trail with experienced travellers

Gives more of a feeling of being guided - being part of the journey

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion:

> Q&A with Seasoned Travellers

(makes it sound more inclusive)

Answer (score 0):

Travel.SE

makes traveling easier!

Answer (score 0):

Explore the world with experienced travelers

Comment: I feel SE does want the phrase "Q&A" in there, and I do too - to give that extra push to show we're not a forum.

Comment: @MarkMayo: As long as it doesn't end up as "Travel Answers" - for some reason that bugs the hell out of me even though a few SE sites have it.

Answer (score 0):

Q&A for here, there, and getting from here to there

Answer (score 0):

Travel Q&A - ask us - we've been there!

Answer (score -1):

If there was a way to work in "We've been there!" that would be great, but is that too long?

> Q & A on travel and destinations: anywhere, any reason, any budget - we've been there!

Answer (score -1):

`{What|Where|When|Why}` about the World?

No "Q&A..." required :)

Answer (score -2):

"Answer site for Seasoned Travellers"

Comment: Sounds too much like "Seasoned Advice" - cooking.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -2):

One more suggestion :

`"I came, I saw, I answered"`

Answer (score -3):

The original:

> Q&A site for Road warriors and seasoned travellers

Comment: Dammit, this should be one less as I want to vote against it, but can't since I wrote it ;)

Comment: I addewd the -1 for ya!

Answer (score -4):

"Q&A for Seasoned Travellers"

(closer to the original but may scare off newbies?)

Comment: Downvoted because I also think it will scare off newbies

Comment: Sounds too much like "Seasoned Advice" cooking.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -4):

"Q&A site for travel junkies"

(or is junkies a bad word?)